# Showing Error(TAble already exist)

Tags: database

--

### -- Database: `25backup2019`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`

CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1050 - Table 'wp_commentmeta' already exists

Answer (score -1):

Try with this, It will delete existing wp_commentmeta table then create 'wp_commentmeta' table :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta`;
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: thanks I have made it out